# The argument type 'User? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[image: The argument type 'User? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'.]
The argument type 'User? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

line 10's function param type should be nullable i.e.

```
User? _userFromFirebaseUser(auth.User? user) {
    // continue function here
}
```

Edit 1:
Apologies, you also need to change your return type to non-nullable. Meaning your `_userFromFirebaseUser` function can no longer return null.

```
User _userFromFirebaseUser(auth.User? user) {
    // continue function here without returning null as option
}
```